# How to install PHP on a UNIX machine that has Apache Tomcat installed

Tags: java, php, apache, unix, tomcat

just looking for some insight and guidance on how I can install PHP on this apache-tomcat web server. So basically I have a Unix box which has 3.14.8-bone5 GNU/Linux and an apache-tomcat-7.0.42 webserver running on it, as far as I know tomcat is used to serve JSP and doesn't use PHP.

From my initial research, it looks like there is a java library that allows tomcat to use PHP? http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/doc/tomcat6.php I tried following this tutorial but I am having troubles:

1. I downloaded the JavaBridgeTemplate713.war file and placed into the apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps directory.
2. Tried this URL in a web browser http://169.254.1.1/JavaBridgeTemplate713/index.php but the page says "Could not run PHP"

   ```
    exception

    php.java.fastcgi.FCGIProcessException: Could not run PHP
    root cause

   java.io.IOException: PHP not found. Please install php-cgi. PHP test 
   command was: [php-cgi, -v] 
   php.java.fastcgi.FCGIProcess.start(FCGIProcess.java:398)
   php.java.fastcgi.SocketFactory.doBind(SocketFactory.java:140)
   php.java.fastcgi.FCGIFactory.runFcgi(FCGIFactory.java:146)
   php.java.fastcgi.FCGIFactory$1.run(FCGIFactory.java:169)
   ```

Can anyone tell me how I can get the PHP-CGI installed on this Unix box?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet to run PHP on top of Tomcat is probably to download and install the Quercus WAR file. Quercus is a Java-based implementation of PHP 5, and it can be found at http://quercus.caucho.com/.

(hat tip to @brian-showalter)